# Shortjournal biblist: how change sorting and solve same shortjournal problems?

Tags: biblatex

I have an extensive bibliography, composed of numerous articles taken from journals.

For editorial reasons, I need to include **the abbreviations of the journal titles** and, just after the final bibliography, the index of the consulted journals. The ideal command is, of course, `\printbiblist{shortjournal}`, with the insertion of `shortjournal={}` in each entry in the `.bib` file.

These are my special inputs:

```
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shortjournal}{%
  \printfield{journaltitle}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorttitle}{%
  \printfield{title}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\em\printfield{shortjournal}}

\AtBeginBiblist{shortjournal}{\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\em#1}}
```

However, I have got two problems that I need to solve.

**The first** concerns the sorting of the list of abbreviations. I would like it to be alphabetical: alphabetical with reference to the abbreviation. Please, note that, of course, it is the duty of any compiler, who chooses the abbreviation, to avoid duplicates in order to prevent confusion in the abbreviations themselves: that implies and means that a single level of sorting is enough. However, it seems to me that by default the order is that of citation.

I have tried to modify the refcontext (`\newrefcontext{sorting=sortshortjournals}`) and to create a sorting template (`\DeclareSortingTemplate{sortshortjournals}`) whose only field is, indeed, shortjournal (`{\sort{\field{SHORTJOURNAL}}}`). However, I have failed.

**The second problem** is that for each article I cite from a journal — no matter of whether the volume, issue, and/or year —, the list cites the abbreviation again. Instead, I want there to be only one item for each abbreviation. In this regard, I have not even been able to hypothesize some attempts.

This is my example: [ciccio_example_shortjournal_list](https://it.overleaf.com/6683174771rrmhpnzzdgsj#d4dca6).

***By the way***: it matters if I use `journal={}`, instead of `journaltitle={}`, in the entries (I know the difference, however, with `issuetitle={}`)?

**Addition** to comply with the preliminary feedbacks. I include all the code, to reproduce my problem directly in the question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@XDATA{jtif,
    JOURNALTITLE = {Journal of Tremendously Interesting Facts},
    SHORTJOURNAL = {JTIF},
}

@XDATA{jtio,
    JOURNALTITLE = {Journal of Tremendously Interesting Opinions},
    SHORTJOURNAL = {JTIO},
}

@ARTICLE{test1,
    AUTHOR = {John Smith},
    TITLE = {Nothing to do},
    SHORTHAND = {JSNTD},
    SHORTTITLE = {NTD},
    XDATA = {jtif},
    VOLUME = {2},
    NUMBER = {1},
    YEAR = {1947}
}
@ARTICLE{test2,
    AUTHOR = {John Tumble},
    TITLE = {I am so happy},
    SHORTHAND = {JTISH},
    SHORTTITLE = {ISH},
    XDATA = {jtif},
    VOLUME = {1},
    NUMBER = {1},
    YEAR = {1946}
}
@ARTICLE{test3,
    AUTHOR = {Francis Coppola},
    TITLE = {I come from Italy},
    SHORTHAND = {FCICFI},
    SHORTTITLE = {ICFI},
    XDATA = {jtif},
    VOLUME = {2},
    NUMBER = {3},
    YEAR = {1947}
}
@ARTICLE{test5,
    AUTHOR = {Francis Coppola},
    TITLE = {I hate Milan},
    SHORTHAND = {FCIHM},
    SHORTTITLE = {IHM},
    XDATA = {jtio},
    VOLUME = {9},
    NUMBER = {1},
    YEAR = {1954}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shortjournal}{%
  \printfield{journaltitle}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorttitle}{%
  \printfield{title}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\em\printfield{shortjournal}}

\AtBeginBiblist{shortjournal}{\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\em#1}}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{sortshortjournals}{
        \sort{\field{SHORTJOURNAL}}
        \sort{\field{JOURNALTITLE}}
    }

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

% \printshorthands% With biber, just an alias for \printbiblist{shorthand}
\printbibliography

\vspace{32pt}

\newrefcontext{sorting=sortshortjournals}
\noindent\textbf{Please, I would like each element to be indicated only once and not multiple times, as it is now. Then, I prefere an alphabetical order too.}
\printbiblist[title={Journal Shorthands}]{shortjournal}
% As you can see, the list shows me more time the same item
% I prefere to have only once the same item
% Possible, in alphabetical order

% \printbiblist[title={Title Shorthands}]{shorttitle}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could minimise your example so much that it can be posted directly into the question? I couldn't access your Overleaf example just now when I tried (and even if it would have worked, off-site examples are generally discouraged, because they might disappear leaving the question without important context).

Comment: New link: https://it.overleaf.com/6683174771rrmhpnzzdgsj#d4dca6

Comment: That link still requires an Overleaf account. Please include all the code required to reproduce your problem directly in the question.

Comment: Done. I am sorry. I will be diligent next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the correct sorting you need to define a sorting template called `shortjournal`. In order to print journal abbreviations only once you can define a bibcheck as shown in [the `biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (§3.8.3 *Bibliography Lists*, pp. 95-97).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{journalsubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}
       {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
          \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
          \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
          \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}
       {\printfield[journaltitle]{shortjournal}}%
     \newunit}%
  \iffieldundef{journaltitleaddon}
    {}
    {\printfield{journaltitleaddon}}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shortjournal}{%
  \printfield{journaltitle}}

\defbibcheck{shortjournal}{%
   \iffieldundef{shortjournal}
     {\skipentry}
     {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}
       {\skipentry}
       {\ifcsdef{sjcheck@\therefsection
          -\strfield{shortjournal}=\strfield{journaltitle}}
         {\skipentry}
         {\savefieldcs{journaltitle}{sjcheck@\therefsection
            -\strfield{shortjournal}=\strfield{journaltitle}}}}}}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{shortjournal}{
  \sort{\field{SHORTJOURNAL}}
  \sort{\field{JOURNALTITLE}}
}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorttitle}{%
  \printfield{title}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@XDATA{jtif,
    JOURNALTITLE = {Journal of Tremendously Interesting Facts},
    SHORTJOURNAL = {JTIF},
}

@XDATA{jtio,
    JOURNALTITLE = {Journal of Tremendously Interesting Opinions},
    SHORTJOURNAL = {JTIO},
}
@ARTICLE{test1,
    AUTHOR = {John Smith},
    TITLE = {Nothing to do},
    SHORTHAND = {JSNTD},
    SHORTTITLE = {NTD},
    XDATA = {jtif},
    VOLUME = {2},
    NUMBER = {1},
    YEAR = {1947}
}
@ARTICLE{test2,
    AUTHOR = {John Tumble},
    TITLE = {I am so happy},
    SHORTHAND = {JTISH},
    SHORTTITLE = {ISH},
    XDATA = {jtif},
    VOLUME = {1},
    NUMBER = {1},
    YEAR = {1946}
}
@ARTICLE{test3,
    AUTHOR = {Francis Coppola},
    TITLE = {I come from Italy},
    SHORTHAND = {FCICFI},
    SHORTTITLE = {ICFI},
    XDATA = {jtif},
    VOLUME = {2},
    NUMBER = {3},
    YEAR = {1947}
}
@ARTICLE{test5,
    AUTHOR = {Francis Coppola},
    TITLE = {I hate Milan},
    SHORTHAND = {FCIHM},
    SHORTTITLE = {IHM},
    XDATA = {jtio},
    VOLUME = {9},
    NUMBER = {1},
    YEAR = {1954}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\printbiblist[title={Journal Shorthands}]{shortjournal}
% As you can see, the list shows me more time the same item
% I prefere to have only once the same item
% Possible, in alphabetical order

% \printbiblist[title={Title Shorthands}]{shorttitle}

\end{document}
```

[image: JTIF Journal of Tremendously Interesting Facts JTIO Journal of Tremendously Interesting Opinions]